# Can't load Caffe model with DummyData layer

Tags: caffe, dummy-data, opencv-contrib

when I try to load a caffe model with OpenCV 3.4.3, I get the error

```
what(): OpenCV(3.4.3) /home/schneider/libs/opencv-3.4.3/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:412: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "DummyData1" of type "DummyData" in function 'getLayerInstance'*
```

The layer in the prototxt file looks like this:

```
layer {
name: "DummyData1"
type: "DummyData"
top: "DummyData1"
dummy_data_param {
    shape {
    dim: 1
    dim: 32
    dim: 125
    dim: 100
          }
   }
}
```

It appears that the layer is missing in OpenCV. The caffe layer is described here on the Caffe webpage, but I am not sure how to implement this layer in OpenCV. Has it already been implemented somewhere? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you able to change a `.protptxxt` the file you can replace these line to the following ones. Try this gys

```
layer {
    type: "Input"
    name: "DummyData1"
    top: "DummyData1"
    input_param {
     shape {
     dim: 1
     dim: 32
     dim: 125
     dim: 100
          }
        }
     }
```

or

```
input: "DummyData1"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 32
input_dim: 125
input_dim: 100
```